# VSC for NodeJS, VueJS... What for Wysiwyg HTML?

Tags: html, vue.js, wysiwyg

**As a pro:**
For years, I have been DEVELOPING SPECIFIC and heterogeneous 'web' APPLICATIONS (a bit of UI)
These are applications that work on a web browser but not necessarily (rarely even) on the WWW.

Backend side: I used to php/mysql but now I much prefer Javascript, NodeJS and so on.
Frontend side: (HTML / CSS / JS / DOM / SVG) I use…. nothing.
Everything by hand with Notepad ++ (Web pages with simple renderings, no nice graphics, just functional)

**As a private:**  (and improving skills!):
I am considering making a real frontend dev site or two. (backend = nodejs (too good!) and DB mysql)
I saw the big React / Angular / Vue competition a bit ... With some difficulty, I chose: I will learn VueJS ...

**THE QUESTION:**
BUT is there still nothing about easy editing (WYSIWYG) of HTML ??? !!!!!!
I'm not talking about software that does the functional code for me, I'm talking about something that allows you to create / choose / place graphic elements on the page (and which therefore generates the html code ...)

So, reals NodeJS + VueJS developers, or others, **with what do you make your beautiful HTML pages???**
I Don't believe that you do all those pretty pages all by hand !!!
Is there no IDE with a Wysiwyg editor (... free or open source preferably)?
(Excluding cms and stuff like wix ...)

I saw this: But it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for ... (except poorly read ...)
unotes Markdown, EditorJS, TinyMCE, Froala,
VSC (seems top but no Wysiwyg html ??!)

Thank you

Comment: Basically, use VScode and display on the screen thanks to frontend languages (html + css). With some hot module reload, you can get a quick visual result. Otherwise, you can use tools like Wordpress or Webflow.

Comment: Thanks. So, I WRITE code and see result "With some hot module reload". can you tell me witch ? thank you !